# Webapi. Define default Json value when enum property is missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi that accepts Post as followed (example)

```
public Foo Post(MyInfo info)
        {
            return new Foo();
        }
```

MyInfo could be something like this

```
public class MyInfo 
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "n")]
        public int MyInt1{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "v")]
        public string MyString1{ get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine when my desktop application (version 1) post a request to this webapi. I serialize the object with a JsonConverter.

Now let's say, I want to add a new parameter to MyInfo as followed

```
 public class MyInfo 
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "n")]
            public int MyInt1{ get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "v")]
            public string MyString1{ get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "s")]
            public MyEnum EnumValue{ get; set; }
    }
```

I update the website and the webapi and I publish a new version of my desktop application (version 2).

The webapi works fine with the version 2 of my desktop application. However, when I use my version 1, the parameter (MyInfo info) in the webapi ends null.
As a reminder, the version 1 sends the exact same MyInfo object except that one property is missing.

How can I avoid this problem and define a default value if the property is missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact the problem was that I had two properties with the same Json property name.

It was completly unrelated to the default value.